# Excel filters don't show after importing the file to sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel

**Excel filters don't show after importing the file to SharePoint Online**

My excel file has 30 filters and after I import it to SharePoint Online the file only shows around 10 filters. Why is this? Is there any workaround this issue?